# Having issues with arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a homework problem that is asking me to write a program that generates 20 random numbers (0-99) in an array and then sorts and prints them.

I am getting crazy errors in my methods and I can't figure out whats wrong. I keep getting errors "Illegal start of expression, ; expected and .class expected. Any advice would be great.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class P6_14
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("This program will sort randomly generated numbers");

        public static int[] createNumbers(int n)
        {
        int[] numbers = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);
        }
        return numbers;
       }

       public static void orderArray(int[] array)
       {
        Arrays.sort(array);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: You don't put the createNumbers and orderArray methods inside the main method

Comment: Also the closing bracket for `main` is at the end, when it should be right after it

Comment: "Illegal start of expression", "; expected" and one I never heard before ".class expected"

Comment: @TheDude  I got the program to compile by putting a curly bracket after my program description, taking the methods out of the main method. Any idea why it wouldn't be displaying anything though?

Answer (score 0):

The way your trying to fit everything into one main method isnt very OOP. Try to create methods in the future within your class! Hope this help

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Hello{

  private  int[] numbers = new int[20]; 


  public  Hello(){
       for (int i = 0; i < this.numbers.length; i++)
    {
        this.numbers[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*99);

    }


  }

   public  void orderArray()
   {
      Arrays.sort(this.numbers);
   }

   public void printArray()
   {

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
       System.out.println(this.numbers[i]);
    }

   }




public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("This program will sort randomly generated numbers1");

    Hello test = new Hello();

    System.out.println("Printing randomized");
    test.printArray();
    test.orderArray();
    System.out.println("Printing sorted");
    test.printArray();



   }

}
```

Comment: unfortunately we haven't yet learned object oriented programming, so I would not be aloud to use it in this assignment.

Comment: @user3658268 Java ***IS*** OOP. You cannot create a method inside a method. Methods are only available to be created inside a class.